# Clickable Link in Editable TextView ios 6

Tags: iphone, ios6

I set the editable property of UITextView yes as I need the UITextView editable then in that case How could be possible to click the link in UITextView ? Is there anyway to fix out my problem

Comment: This looks like a genuine bug in ios 6, a valid issue in fact. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350971/ios-6-uitextview-link-detection-issue. A UITextview link placed on a UIView doesn't seem to work on ios 6.

Comment: So in fact this question isn't a duplicate, it looks like an ios 6 bug.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set detect type of `UITextView` in implementation file like

```
textview.editable = NO;
textview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited it wrong. But one concern is: OP wanted the editable `UITextView` and also make the `Link` clickable. Which is not possible by this solution.

Comment: you can implement the edit text method of UITextView and on changes the text, you can check if the user changes the url or normal text.

Comment: This doesn't work when one uses a link in a UITextView placed on a UIView. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350971/ios-6-uitextview-link-detection-issue